# what is WOW effect in music o/p configuration?

Tags: windows-xp, music, windows-media-player

Windows Media Player and some other well known players give an option of setting up WOW effect, what is the abbreviation of WOW? and how it matters in alteration of sound effects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [website for SRS](http://mediaplayer.srswowcast.com/features.html) who are the creators of the technology:

> SRS WOW HD™ - greatly expands the size
>   of the audio image, retrieves
>   information lost in the mixing process
>   and creates deep, rich bass response
>   for a more natural audio experience.

I was not able to determine what WOW stands for, but it might also just be "'wow', that sounds good" for all I know.

Answer (score 3):

From [Toshiba's Glossary:](http://www.tacp.toshiba.com/televisions/glossary.asp?fid=166)

> SRS® WOW™ consists of three separate sound expanding systems, which work together to extract"buried" highs and lows. The three systems are, SRS® 3D, TruBass™, and FOCUS™. SRS® 3D creates a three dimensional sound field from just two speakers, thus giving the listener the feeling of hearing a multi speaker surround sound system. TruBass™ produces a powerful, yet low, frequency sound by utilizing a process called psychoacoustics. From only two small speakers, TruBass™ will give the effect of an expensive sub bass woofer that will leave the listener amazed by the quality of the sound. FOCUS was added to direct the energy from the speakers of the televisio

In lay-person speak, it's a technology comprising of three separate techniques to improve the bass & treble output from speakers - allowing for 3-dimensional sound effects from 2 speakers